# "As" operator for constrained generic types

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2009

Consider:

```
TTest <T : class, constructor> = class 
public
  function CreateMyObject : T;
end;
function TTest<T>.CreateMyObject : T;
var
  Obj : TObject;
begin
  Obj := T.Create; 
  Result := (Obj as T);
end;
```

Why isn't this possible? Compiler yields an "Operator not applicable to this type" error message for the **as** operator. T is constrained to be a class type, so this should work, shouldn't it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No. That would be an invalid typecast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by adding a low-level pointer-copy method to the class as a workaround:

```
  TTest <T : class, constructor> = class
  private
    function _ToGeneric(AItem: TObject): T; inline; //inline, so it's a little faster
  public
    function CreateMyObject : T;
  end;

  function TTest<T>.CreateMyObject : T;
  var
    Obj : TObject;
  begin
    Obj := T.Create;
    Result := _ToGeneric(Obj);
  end;

  function TTest<T>._ToGeneric(AItem: TObject): T;
  begin
    System.Move(AItem,Result,SizeOf(AItem))
  end;
```

Comment: +1 That seems to work! Nice workaround. I hope that will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a known issue](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=75435) with the Delphi compiler.  Please vote for it if you'd like to see it fixed.  In the meantime, you can work around it by saying

```
Result := (Obj as TClass(T));
```

Comment: Hi Mason! Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately your workaround does not compile for me ("'(' expected but ')' found")

Comment: Ack!  If that doesn't work for your version then MvdH's answer might be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it doesn't work. I assume there are still some quirks/bugs in the generics implementation.

But the following code works:

```
// Class definition
function CreateMyObject<T : class, constructor>  : T;


// Class implementation
function TForm1.CreateMyObject<T>: T;
var
  Obj : T;
begin
  Obj := T.Create;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, this works but unfortunately I can only create a TObject, since I use TClass.Create to create the object. It's for a factory class (see my other recent questions)

Comment: Why don't you use a common ancestor with a virtual constructor? Yo can create a class of type and use that (and not TClass)?

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail? As I understand it this does not help because I want the return value to be of type T and not of type TCommonAncestor.

Comment: I will answer this evening. Then I have time to test this. But I have met some dead ends using generics so prepare for the worst...