# Problem with Generics and As Cast

Tags: delphi, generics, casting, delphi-xe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“As” operator for constrained generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237740/as-operator-for-constrained-generic-types)

The following reduced sample code produces a compiler error when trying to cast to the generic type using the `as` operator. Strangely enough the combination of the `is` operator and a hard cast does work as expected.

```
program Project8;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Controls, StdCtrls;

type
  TControlWrapperBase = class
  protected
    FCtrl : TControl;
  public
    constructor Create (Ctrl : TControl);
  end;

  TControlWrapper <T : TControl> = class (TControlWrapperBase)
  public
    function GetControl : T;
  end;


constructor TControlWrapperBase.Create(Ctrl : TControl);
begin
FCtrl := Ctrl;
end;


function TControlWrapper <T>.GetControl : T;
begin
Result := FCtrl as T;     // does not compile: E2010 Incompatible Types: TEdit and TControl

if FCtrl is T then        // this does work
  Result := T (FCtrl);
end;

var
  Wrapper : TControlWrapper <TEdit>;
  MyCtl   : TEdit;

begin
try
  MyCtl := TEdit.Create(nil);
  TControlWrapper <TEdit>.Create (MyCtl).GetControl;
except
  on E: Exception do
    Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
end;

end.
```

How can this compiler error be overcome?

Comment: I can reproduce this; `as` cast fails to compile with 'incompatible types' error. Now, what's the question? :-) BTW, the `as` cast seems superfluous. You can safely hardcast `T(FCtrl)` since `T` is constrained to be a `TControl` (or descendant).

Comment: @TOndrej: question is: why does it fail? Is it a compiler bug?

Comment: Yes, personally, I consider it a compiler bug. It seems logical that the cast should succeed. Also, the compiler has the knowledge it needs to validate such a cast.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: ["As" operator for constrained generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237740/as-operator-for-constrained-generic-types)

However, I don't understand why you can't write it like this:

```
type
  TControlWrapper<T: TControl> = class
  private
    FCtrl: T;
  public
    property Ctrl: T read FCtrl;
  end;
```

Comment: I posted a simplified extract. Basically we need access to the control when working with the base type but want to get the specialized control without casting when working with the derived type.

Comment: Just realized that I myself asked the question you link to :) Too late already...

Comment: My code above would allow all of that.

Comment: Aww shame on you for posting not only a duplicate, but a duplicate of your own question!!  ;-)

Comment: the problem is that `TControlWrapper <TEdit>` and `TControlWrapper <TComboBox>` do not have a common base class. By letting the generic `TControlWrapper<T>` inherit from `TControlWrapper`and exposing the `TControl` there, we can use all control wrappers using the common base type.

Answer (score 1):

You have already asked nearly [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511247/howto-cast-pointer-to-generic-parameter-type) more than 2 years ago. I don't know what changed in Delphi generics since then, but probably Barry Kelly's answer is still valid - the compiler can't typecast generics because

> Unfortunately, the compiler is not
>   smart enough to figure out that a
>   class-type constraint means that T is
>   guaranteed to be the same size as a
>   pointer.

Comment: Actually we now have 3 versions of the same question, all asked by @Smasher. Wow!

Comment: well, yeah, I should have searched more carefully. But on the other hand it's not my fault that these things didn't get fixed in over two years now. BTW: the QC report posted by Mason Wheeler in the duplicate question is closed as fixed...

Comment: how is that nearly the same question? That's not even the same compiler error. With all the bugs in generics (in 2009 at least, and apparently still in XE) these subtle differences do matter.